# Cannot invoke reloadData with no arguments UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

In my game app I'm having difficulty with my LobbyViewController (a list of available games to play). `self.tableView.reloadData()` is throwing an error `Cannot invoke reloadData with no arguments`. It's throwing this error because I have the LobbyViewController class inheriting from a custom BaseViewController for navigation. The problem goes away when I change it to inherit from UITableViewController, but then I don't get the custom navigation created with BaseViewController.

How can I get `self.tableView.reloadData()` to work when LobbyViewController inherits from BaseViewController?

Here is a gist of the relevant files:

https://gist.github.com/jtansley/2f8710b3cc410be1f715

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's ok that `BaseViewController` does not inherit from `TableViewController`. In which case you need an `@IBoutlet` reference to an actual `UITableView` in your `LobbyViewController`.

Drag your `UITableView` from the storyboard onto your `LobbyViewController` and then you should see

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

you should be able to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This got rid of the error but the table is empty when I run the app. I think it's because I the UITableView is covering up the original TableViewController. What should I do?

Comment: It's hard to debug without seeing the storyboard. If you're using a `UITableViewController`, it comes with a free `UITableView`, and there's also no need to drag that `@IBOutlet` reference as mentioned in the answer(ish).

Another thing you might want to do is remove all your constraints on the table view, it may be easier to just start again so you can see where everything is laid out.

Comment: OK, that's what I suspected. How can I make it work with the free UITableView? Shouldn't it recognize it already?

Comment: How can I get it to recognize the tableview?

Comment: Remember to set up a `delegate` and a `dataSource`, and implement the proper override methods in your class.

Comment: I have the delegate and datasource setup. I tried moving the function that contains `self.tableView.reloadData()` within the datasource class but I still get the error. This is so frustrating!.